# How to get view mode of a node?

Tags: 8, nodes

So my question is how I can get programmatically in preprocess node hook, the display mode of a node, for example, to check if view mode is a teaser or full?

Answer (score 8):

The view mode is in the vars:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $view_mode = $vars['view_mode'];
}
```

See [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x) or [node.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for respond Clive. Exactly what I've needed so proper condition would be                                                                                             `$view_mode = $vars['view_mode'];
  if ($view_mode == 'easer') {                                                                   Do something                                                                                                    }`

Comment: Exactly right :) (well, you might want a "t" in the "easer" but I'm guessing you know tha)

Comment: @leymannx Just FYI I reverted that last edit, I didn't see the improvement in it - preprocess hooks are equally valid in modules or themes

Comment: I just applied standard indentation, wrote `$variables` out, and prefixed the hook with `MYTHEME` as you linked to the `template_*` hook and not to `hook_preprocess_HOOK`.

Comment: `template_preprocess_node` is in a module @leymannx...

Comment: I always thought they are prefixed `template_` as they are supposed to be used in themes (`template.php`, now `*.theme`). Always confuses me why there seems to be so many duplicate documentation as both hooks are doing just the same...

Comment: @leymannx If memory serves this goes back to a convention that grew up from D6 - `template_preprocess_*` is basically Drupal's way of saying _this theme has an implied, required preprocess that sets up variables, and here it is_. If I had to guess, I'd say it was to ensure that those required variables would be available to modules/themes subsequently implementing the preprocess hook. Otherwise, if it was `node_preprocess_node`, for example, the node module would have to fight with the other modules implementing the same hook in terms of module weight. `foo_preprocess_node`...

Comment: ...wouldn't have access to `$vars['node']`, and so on

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense! So one could say `template_preprocess_node` is just a consolidated/fixed version of `hook_preprocess_HOOK`?!

Comment: Yeah pretty much @leymannx :)