# Function to get node view mode name

Tags: 8, nodes

I've been using

```
$node->getType();
```

to get the content type.

For view mode, I am following [this method](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231648/how-to-get-view-mode-of-a-node):

Is there a function similar to `getType()` (that doesn't require adding a preprocess function) I can use to get the view mode of my node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node entity represents the database content of the node, which can be displayed in different view modes. If you want to alter such a display in a specific view mode use `mymodule_node_view_alter()`:

```
function hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'full' && isset($build['an_additional_field'])) {

    // Change its weight.
    $build['an_additional_field']['#weight'] = -10;

    // Add a #post_render callback to act on the rendered HTML of the entity.
    $build['#post_render'][] = 'my_module_node_post_render';
  }
}
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.7.x